# Trying to show $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n)i)\supset \mathbb Q(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n )i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am not sure if the following is true, $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n)i)\supset \mathbb Q(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n )i)$.

My attempt is to look at powers of $\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n)i$ and to see if I can obtain $i\sin$ or $\cos$ by itself. For convenience I use cos and sin to represent the expressions $\cos(2\pi/n)$ and $\sin(2\pi/n)$.
Even though I eliminate cos when I subtract $(\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n))^3-(\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n))$ we get $-2\sin\cdot(1-\sin^2) + i(2s\cdot(1-s^2)$. Division at this point is not going to help because I cannot divide by $\sin$. Can I get a hint if the above claim is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have looked at enough powers yet :
For any integer $k$, $(\cos(2\pi/n)+i \sin(2\pi/n))^k = \cos(2k\pi/n) +i \sin(2k\pi/n)$.
So $(\cos(2\pi/n)+i \sin(2\pi/n))^{n-1} = \cos(2\pi/n) -i \sin(2\pi/n)$, and it's easy from there.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $z\in\mathbb C$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then so is $\overline{z}$ and with the same minimal polinomial. So, if you denote $z=\cos(2\pi/n)+\sin(2\pi/n)i$, then $\overline z\in \mathbb Q(z)$. Then $z+\overline z, z-\overline z\in\mathbb Q(z)$